# Как отследить в базе данных измененные записи

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть база данных LocalDB, в нее поступают данные и эти данные меняются, какие есть методы чтобы отслеживать какие строки в таблицах изменились. Например, вот я загрузил в таблицы базы данные, работаю с данными, далее мне нужно взять данные из базы и отправить в другое место (непринципиально куда), встает вопрос, брать все данные из всех таблиц и отправлять адресату или логичнее все таки отследить изменение и взять только измененные данные. Как можно  организовать такой процесс. Добавлять в каждую строку таблицы флаг? Хочется как то сделать механизм средствами самой базы.

Comment: Можно выполнять свои действия при изменении/удалении/вставке записей с помощью так называемых [*триггеров*](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Но вам нужны не триггеры, вам нужна синхронизация. Обычно вам нужно предусмотреть набор данных для синхронизации, например, дату-время создания записи. В сложных случаях это может вылиться в [хранение событий изменения вместо сущностей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Событийно-ориентированная_архитектура). Простого ответа здесь нет, придётся много читать и экспериментировать.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Спасибо за комментарий, я и не жду простого ответа, просто до сегодняшнего дня не занимался такими вопросами и сейчас встала надобность, вот хочется узнать что вообще в таких случаях делают.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с триггерами плюс служебная таблица. В которую триггер просто пишет ID изменившейся записи, если её там ещё нет. И для синхронизации выгружаете записи, ID коих есть в таблице, после чего таблицу чистите - пусть накапливаются следующие изменённые. Как показывает опыт, это эффективнее, чем поле (изменённости или штампа времени актуализации) в самОй таблице.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за хорошую идею, а как триггер отслеживает что записи в таблицах изменились? Насколько сложен сам код такого триггера?

Comment: *как триггер отслеживает что записи в таблицах изменились?* Никак. Он просто срабатывает на указанное действие, и при этом имеет доступ к начальному и конечному состоянию либо каждой изменяемой записи, либо всего массива сразу.

Comment: посмотрите https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: [SqlDependency](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)